# How can I specifically enqueue scripts for edit orders pages only

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

The problem is that enqueing script this way, I end up inadvertently targeting product pages and other pages also which use the `post` and `post-new` hook, as WordPress has many types of posts, not only orders.  I *only* want to target Woocommerce view individual order and create new order admin pages.  (Not orders list, just individual orders.)

```
function selectively_enqueue_admin_script_js_for_edit_address( $hook ) {
    if ( 'post.php' != $hook and 'post-new.php' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'artio-wc-admin-order-page-mod', '/wp-content/plugins/custom_wc_mods/order_page/paste_payment_instructions_and_prompts_into_shipping_address_form_v2.js', array(), date("h:i:s") );
    /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/31834007 */
    /* During development, you could avoid the hassle of clearing the browser cache by passing a dynamic variable as the file's version when you enqueue it. For instance, the current time. */
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'selectively_enqueue_admin_script_js_for_edit_address' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by checking current `post_type`. For woocommerce order page, post type is `shop_order`. So try to change your code as follows.

```
function selectively_enqueue_admin_script_js_for_edit_address($hook)
{
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type === 'shop_order') {
        if ($hook === 'post.php' || $hook === 'post-new.php') {
            wp_enqueue_script('artio-wc-admin-order-page-mod', '/wp-content/plugins/custom_wc_mods/order_page/paste_payment_instructions_and_prompts_into_shipping_address_form_v2.js', array(), date("h:i:s"));
            /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/31834007 */
            /* During development, you could avoid the hassle of clearing the browser cache by passing a dynamic variable as the file's version when you enqueue it. For instance, the current time. */
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'selectively_enqueue_admin_script_js_for_edit_address');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since WooCommerce **High Performance Order Storage** (HPOS) is not relying on post tables. So, in that case, you can add scripts with the below code.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'selectively_enqueue_admin_script_js_for_edit_address' );

function selectively_enqueue_admin_script_js_for_edit_address() {
    $screen    = get_current_screen();
    $screen_id = $screen ? $screen->id : '';
    
    if ( $screen_id === wc_get_page_screen_id( 'shop-order' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'artio-wc-admin-order-page-mod', '/wp-content/plugins/custom_wc_mods/order_page/paste_payment_instructions_and_prompts_into_shipping_address_form_v2.js', array(), date("h:i:s") );
            /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/31834007 */
            /* During development, you could avoid the hassle of clearing the browser cache by passing a dynamic variable as the file's version when you enqueue it. For instance, the current time. */
    }
}
```